# AngularJS : Access to isolate scope with replace in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I want to know if there is a way to access the scope of directive if I have set the replace option to true. For example, here is the initial jsbin:
http://jsbin.com/ABuSODub/2/edit

When you click on `x`, the directive closes. `close()` function is defined on the directive's own isolate scope. However, if I set replace to true, the thing stops working which is understandable because there is no directive anymore.

Can it be made to work? It there a better approach. I really do not want to set close function on parent controller. Or is it some other problem entirely which I do not see?

Comment: Your code is throwing errors `TypeError: Cannot call method 'split' of undefined`

Comment: @IlanFrumer Sorry for that. I have fixed those and updated the link above.

Comment: problem is with ng-if creating a new nested scope so transcluded element cannot see parent properly . You can test by removing ng-if with ng-show and your problem will be resolved easlily

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do with the click event is set open = false, you don't need to call a function to do that.  Consider this template revision:

```
'<div class="alert-box {{box}}" data-ng-if="open" data-ng-init="open = false"><span data-ng-transclude></span><a href="#" class="close" data-ng-click="open = !open">&times;</a></div>',
```

Comment: Yes that will solve the problem. But I think this open will pollute the controller's scope and will lead to funny things when multiple alerts get involved in same scope. If I close one, won't it affect all others?

Comment: It shouldn't.  I have used that strategy in an ng-repeat (building a tree view) with no problems.